# PlotWidget в QWidget

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, pyside2, pyqtgraph

В гуи на *Pyside2* нужно добавить график. 
Для построения графика использую *pyqtgraph*.

```
    self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
    self.toolBox.addItem(self.page_3, "Визуализация")

    self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()

    self.layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
    self.groupBox3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
    self.groupBox3.setLayout(self.layout)
```

выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
PySide2.QtWidgets.QLayout.addWidget(PlotWidget)
Supported signatures:
PySide2.QtWidgets.QLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

Как мне тогда добавить виджет с графиком?

Comment: Мб вам поможет, делал через PyQt5 и QtChart: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/045a27845cead070e34167e43aa17fec184e1508/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/chart_line__dark_theme__QtChart.py

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы не предоставили воспроизводимый пример, я продемонстрирую как рисовать график в реальном времени, не блокируя графический интерфейс.

Поменяйте импорты под `PySide2`, так как у меня `PyQt5` и попробуйте.

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QGridLayout, \
    QLabel, QLineEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class MyThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.s  = None    
        self.phase = 0    

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):                    
            self.update()
            self.signal.emit(self.s) 
            self.msleep(200)             

    def update(self):
        self.t = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
        self.s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * self.t + self.phase)    
        self.phase += 0.1
        

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.gridLayoutCreation()
        
        vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vboxLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.setLayout(vboxLayout)

        self.traces = dict()
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)        

    def gridLayoutCreation(self): 
        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Пример компоновки Grid Layout")
        gridLayout   = QGridLayout()
        self.guiplot = pg.PlotWidget()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.guiplot, 0, 8, 8, 12)
        self.groupBox.setLayout(gridLayout)

        gridLayout.addWidget(QLabel('Label'), 0,0)
        self.timeEdit = QLineEdit('Hello World') 
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.timeEdit, 1,0) 

    def plotar(self, s):                                    
        self.guiplot.clear()
        self.guiplot.plot(s)

    def test(self):
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.signal.connect(self.displayS)
        self.thread.start()

    def displayS(self, self_s):                             
        """ Рисуйте график в реальном времени, не блокируя графический интерфейс.
        """
        self.plotar(self_s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    w.test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Но в том-то и проблема, если менять PyQt5 на PySide2, то возникает ошибка

"TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget(PlotWidget, int, int, int, int)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QGridLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget)
"

Comment: @Newman покажите пожалуйста на моем примере какая ошибка у вас возникает ?

Comment: В Вашем примере я просто поменял 
"from PyQt5.QtWidgets" на "from PySide2.QtWidgets".

Comment: @Newman  да, есть нюансы, вам надо прочитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyside2+pyqtgraph